# Edit UITableViewCell pulling data from CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to pull my information from a selected cell from UITableView with

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let resultant = segue.destination as? EditViewController {
        resultant.intention = intentionsArray[(intentionsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
    }

}
```

My EditViewController code is

```
var intention:EIntentions?
```

I keep getting the error below (EIntentions is my entity, eIntentionCell is my string attribute)

> Cannot assign value of type 'NSManagedObject' to type 'EIntentions?'

My array fetching the data from CoreData is

```
var intentionsArray: [NSManagedObject] = []
```

I know it is an error with the NSManagedObject array. Essentially, I'm trying to pass the selected cell's text to a text field in EditViewController. I just cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The error says that `EIntentions` is not a subclass of `NSManagedObject` - How did you create that class?  Was it auto created by the Core Data model?

Comment: Here's a link to the screenshot of CoreData. I created ` EIntentions ` myself when I added CoreData to my project. @Pawlw11 https://www.dropbox.com/s/l65r8ygy7xl1w97/Screenshot%202018-02-05%2019.38.13.png?dl=0

Comment: Once you create an entity in your Core Data model, it should generate the entity classes for you.  It seems that there might be an issue with that process since it is telling you that the EIntentions class isn't an NSManagedObject subclass.  Try deleting your derived data folder

Comment: @Paulw11 I did it and still received the error for some reason

Comment: If you bring up the context menu (right click) on `EIntentions` in Xcode and select "Jump to definition" what does it show you?

Comment: It went to a "EIntentions+CoreDataClass.swift file, which isn't in my nav pane on the right side. The contents are: 
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(EIntentions)
public class EIntentions: NSManagedObject {

}         (sorry for formatting issues @Paulw11)

Comment: So that shows that your `EIntentions` class *is* an `NSManagedObject` subclass.  I don't know why it is giving that error. Have you tried cleaning your project from the Product menu?

Comment: Yes, I've cleaned it and I still get the error when I go to build it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have

```
var intentionsArray: [NSManagedObject] = []
```

This is array of NSManagedObject. And `EditViewController` is expecting `EIntentions` object.

Either way EIntentions and NSManagedObject are totally different objects, that's why you getting this error. You must init

```
var intentionsArray: [EIntentions] = []
```

to make it work like you want. If you've created EIntentions right, then fetching EIntentions objects from database will go smooth and everything will work

Comment: It works! Thank you! Now I can go back to what I've been meaning to finish forever.